# Postman retorna JSON, mas requisição Fetch retorna status 204 no browser

Tags: javascript, json, api, http

Estou fazendo uma requisição com a função `Fetch()`, porém recebo sempre a mesma mensagem, com status 204:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, ao fazer a requisição via POSTMAN, eu recebo status 200, com as informações necessárias:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu código está aqui:

```
fetch(`URL`, {
      method: "GET",
      header: {
        "Access-token": "xxx",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  )
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Erro: ", err);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que você está sendo bloqueado pela politica de cors do seu navegador. Provavelmente isso acontece pois está sendo acessado uma api que possui um dominio diferente do seu código que está fazendo o fetch. Quando você utiliza o postman, não há bloqueio pela politica de cors.

Há duas maneiras de resolver isso:

1ª: desativar o cors do seu navegador (não recomendado, pois é perigoso navegar na web assim)

2ª: no seu servidor backend (referente api que está acessando), colocar uma lista de dominios permitidos.